# Datatable expanded content is loaded when filtering

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a nested datatable using rowExpansion. The content for each nested table is loaded correctly when expanding the row. However, when a filter is applied to the root table, the content for *all* the nested tables is loaded. If there's many rows, this kills performance.

Note that this is not the "JSF calls getters multiple times"-problem. The content for the expanded rows are cached in backing. It behaves as if every single row is expanded before the filter is applied. Note that the filter only concerns the "value" property, not the "strings" which are the expanded content.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{backing.elements}" var="row"
  filteredValue="#{backing.elementsFiltered}">

  <p:column>
    <p:rowToggler />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Value" filterBy="#{row.value}">
    <h:outputText value="#{row.value}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:rowExpansion>
    <p:dataTable value="#{row.strings}" var="string">
      <p:column headerText="Strings">
        <h:outputText value="#{string}" />
      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
  </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

Backing bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Backing implements Serializable {

    private List<Element> elements;
    private List<Element> elementsFiltered;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Load the list of elements.
    }

    public List<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public List<Element> getElementsFiltered() {
        return elementsFiltered;
    }

    public void setElementsFiltered(List<Element> elementsFiltered) {
        this.elementsFiltered = elementsFiltered;
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
public class Element {

    private String value;
    private List<String> strings;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // This getter is called for a particular row when it is expanded.
    // But it is called for all rows when the table is filtered.
    public List<String> getStrings() {
        if (strings == null) {
            // Expensive opperation to load the strings.
        }
        return strings;
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Primefaces 5.3.0, JSF 2.2, Java EE 7.0

Comment: so this does not happen on sorting or paging or initial loading of the datatable? RowExpansion contents is loaded lazily then?

Comment: It does not happen on sorting and initial load. It does however happen for paging, but then only for the elements on the current page.
Yes it is lazy. I kept the example as simple as possible, but strictly speaking the expanded content is loaded through JPA using @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: can you, just for this 'problem', try 6.0-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Yes I'll try the snapshot

Comment: Off-topic (kind of): Personally, I always use lazyloading (and the related filtering etc).

Comment: Just tried with 6.0-SNAPSHOT. It behaves exactly the same.

Comment: Ok, let me try and investigate in the weekend

Comment: Experiencing a similar problem. Hope a resolution is found.

Comment: I ended up binding the sub table, limiting the rowExpansion to 'single', and reset it the table on the rowToggle event to get unbuggy behaviour.